# How to delete Bad Test data in Prod?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to using Rails and migrations. Our application is not fully live yet.

In one of our Prod database tables, we have some bad data (as a result of early testing).

We do not have access to the Prod database/server, so someone our team suggested creating a migration and someone else suggested seeds.rb for this.

Is it better to -
 
1. create a migration for it, or 
2. include some code in seeds.rb (and remove that code later on), or 
3. request Prod admin to delete directly on the Prod server using 'rails console' or 
4. request database admin to delete directly at the database using Sql

Are migrations used to delete data ? Is there a best practice guidance on this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Migrations don't operate on database contents but on the database structure.</strike> Every change to tables and their columns/indices are reflected chronologically in the migration files. Adding a migration to delete data feels wrong when it's executed after creating all schema information. The data should not be there in the first place.

I would purge the production database to start with a clean state. When deploying you maybe already run `rake db:migrate` command to adjust all database changes made in development. This causes all tables to be recreated and since you deleted all database contents before, you have your most recent schema but without any legacy contents.

Comment: Migrations can operate on database contents.  Some people may think it's bad practise but i think it's wrong to say that they don't do it: that implies that they **cannot** change db contents, which isn't true at all.

Comment: But, yes, i agree that if you haven't gone live yet you should delete & recreate your production db and run the migrations from scratch.

Comment: A migration just runs some code, you can do whatever you want :)